# Yum won't update because of newer libstdc++ library. How do I fix this?

Tags: centos, yum, libstdc++

Whenever I try to update my system via "sudo yum update", I get this error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libstdc++-4.3.2-7.i386 (which is newer than libstdc++-4.1.2-51.el5.x86_64) is already installed
```

I'm not sure how I got in this state, but I'm pretty sure that whatever I've done has been through yum.

Here's what "yum list" gives me for that library:

```
libstdc++.x86_64                           4.1.2-50.el5                installed
libstdc++.i386                             4.3.2-7                     installed
libstdc++-devel.x86_64                     4.1.2-50.el5                installed
```

Notice how the i386 version is different than the .x86_64 version.  That's really strange.

I'm running CentOS 5.6 64 bit.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lazy man's method.  For now use --skip-broken so other stuff will update.  And eventually your repo version of libstdc++ will catchup to what's on your box.